# Mysql Exited on Docker Container

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I want to make a web development platform on MacOS by using Docker. I installed nginx, and php7-fpm container and they're running and communicating each other. But after installing mysql container, mysql container was exited. I don't know why it exited.

This is docker ps -a output:

```
2955d2d5c392        nginx               "/sbin/my_init"          38 seconds ago      Up 36 seconds               0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   dockertutorial_web_1
ec3c16795f05        php:7-fpm           "docker-php-entrypoin"   38 seconds ago      Up 37 seconds               9000/tcp               dockertutorial_php_1
835e91ba927a        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   38 seconds ago      Exited (0) 37 seconds ago                          dockertutorial_mysql_1
```

As you can see, mysql was exited.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
web:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./src/public:/var/www/public
    - ./src/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
  links:
    - php


php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./src/public:/var/www/public
    links:
      - mysql

mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/mysql
  command: "true"
  environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: project
        MYSQL_USER: project
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: project
```

Any suggesstion to solve it?

Answer (score -2):

You are overriding `command` for `MySQL` image with `true` which will be run instead of `mysqld`.

Remove `command: "true"` from `docker-compose.yml` from `mysql` service and it will start `mysqld`.

See this Dockerfile for reference.

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/c207cc19a272a6bfe1916c964ed8df47f18479e7/5.7/Dockerfile#L63